# Rewrite rule not matching

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting

I created the rewrite rule

```
add_rewrite_rule("^user/(\d+)/(myaccount)/?", 'index.php?pagename=$matches[2]&user_id=$matches[1]','top');
```

So when a user visits example.com/user/123/myaccount/ it should use the wordpress page with slug 'myaccount' and pass '123' as the user_id.

I have flushed my rewrite rules, and I am using Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer to check but it doesn't seem to match that pattern.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try removing the brackets from `(myaccount)` and changing `pagename` in the URL to `myaccount`: `add_rewrite_rule("^user/(\d+)/myaccount/?", 'index.php?pagename=myaccount&user_id=$matches[1]','top');` (Not tested, so not adding as an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the suggestion from my comment and it worked.

Remove the brackets from `(myaccount)` and change `$matches[2]` in the URL to `myaccount`:

```
function wpse_287203_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^user/(\d+)/myaccount/?', 'index.php?pagename=myaccount&user_id=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_287203_rewrite_rule' );
```

`(myaccount)` will not match a whole world. That's a little more involved. See [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4722036/2684861) for how to match an exact word. We don't need to do that here though, since we can just manually put the word into the second argument of `add_rewrite_rule()`.

Also, it wasn't part of the question, but it's what comes next. To get access to the `user_id`, you need to add it to the list of valid query variables:

```
function wpse_287203_query_vars( $vars ) {
  $vars[] = 'user_id';

  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse_287203_query_vars' );
```

Now you can get the user id when on that URL with `get_query_var()`:

```
$user_id = get_query_var( 'user_id' );
$userdata = get_userdata( $user_id );
```

Comment: it looks like there was another rule taking precedence

    (.?.+?)?(:/([0-9]+))?/?$

I changed my rule to:

    ^user/([^/]+)/myaccount/?

and now I see it working, I also added the query_vars like you suggested
Much help, thanks Jacob

Answer (score -1):

Your rewrite rule `user/(\d+)/(myaccount)/` had an error because of forward slashes. In regular expressions, "/" is a special character which needs to be escaped, which you can do by adding a backslash(/). So your rewrite rule may look something like this:

```
^user\/(\d+)\/(myaccount)\/?
```

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: I don't think that's it. None of the examples in [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) escape the slash.